# Error: Unable to initialize GTK+, is DISPLAY set properly?

Tags: hp-ux, x11-forwarding, bullseye

I am using HP-UX server for code coverage using bullseye. When I run ./CoverageBrowser binary I am getting below error message.

18:28:01: Error: Unable to initialize GTK+, is DISPLAY set properly?

echo $DISPLAY
:11.0

I have enabled X11Forwarding as well.

Comment: If you connected through ssh, did you have a X11 connection (or emuator in Window) and add the -X or the -Y option to forward it?

Answer (score 2):

try run a command `xhost +`

I think, that will be enought.

Comment: Indeed, it was enough, thanks @anton-shevtsov.